# foreach: How to combine two matrices in a list across multiple iterations?

Tags: r, foreach

I want `foreach` to return two matrices in a list each iteration. This return value should be combined with previous iterations by passing a custom function `acomb()` to the `.combine` parameter. The returned list holding the matrices should not be simply combined to form a longer list using `.combine="list"` or `.combine="c"`. Instead, the two matrices should be stacked separately to build two three-dimensional arrays.

The following code works as expected if I perform two iterations (`1:2`), but I receive an error if I increase the number of iterations:

```
require("foreach")
require("abind")

acomb <- function(old, new) list(abind(old$a, new$a, along=3), abind(old$b, new$b, along=3))

foreach(1:3, .combine=acomb, .multicombine=TRUE) %do% {
  list(a=cbind(c(1,2),c(3,4)), b=cbind(c(1,2),c(3,4),c(5,6)))
}
```

The returned error is:

```
Error in { : unused Argument (result.3)
```

Comment: sorry, `require("foreach")` was missing. now the code should reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function accepts only two arguments. Thus, you must set `.multicombine = FALSE`. Since the function needs then to be applied by a `Reduce`-like approach, you must name the list elements in the return value.

```
acomb <- function(old, new) list(a = abind(old$a, new$a, along=3), 
                                 b = abind(old$b, new$b, along=3))

foreach(1:3, .combine=acomb) %do% {
  list(a=cbind(c(1,2),c(3,4)), b=cbind(c(1,2),c(3,4),c(5,6)))
}
```